# Can Anyone help me to load pdf file from firebase to user app by URL in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on a project of android development with Jetpack compose and Firestore. I have wrtite the code for upload the pdf file from the Admin panel. But I am not able to retrive the uploaded file in user Panel. Can anyone give me a code for it.. plzz

I want code or suggestion for loading pdf file from firestore to user panel with jetpack compose.